# php or sed: insert html tag within existing html tag when a string is matched

Tags: php, regex

How can I search for the word "**Box**" within the html code below:

```
<p>Text here ok</p>
<h4>
Box 1.2</h4>
<p>Text here ok</p>
```

and have the output as follows?

```
<p>Text here ok</p>
<h4><a name="box1.2"></a>Box 1.2</h4>
<p>Text here ok</p>
```

Note the line break between `<h4>` and Box needs to be removed. The other thing is I will have "Box 2.0", "Box 2.3", etc. so only the word "Box" has the matching pattern.

Comment: use str_replace() to do it

Comment: Will it always be in `<h4>` tag or it can be inside other HTML tags as well (like div, p, span etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP:

```
$str = '<p>Text here ok</p>
<h4>
Box 1.2</h4>
<p>Text here ok</p>';

$new = preg_replace('/\s*(box)\s*(\d+(:?\.\d+)?)/i', '<a name="$1$2">$1 $2</a>', $str);
echo $new;
```

Explanation:

```
/ #START delimiter
    \s* #match spaces/newlines (optional/several)
    (box) #match "box" and group it (this will be used as $1)
    \s* #match spaces/newlines (optional/several)
    (\d+(:?\.\d+)?) #match a number (decimal part is optional) and group it (this will be used as $2)
/ #END delimiter
i #regex modifier: i => case insensitive
```

Comment: `(\d+(:?\.\d+))` -> `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you going.

```
<?php
$html = '<p>Text here ok</p>
<h4>
Box 1.2</h4>
<p>Text here ok</p>';

$html = preg_replace_callback('~[\r\n]?Box\s+[\d.]+~', function($match){
    $value  = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), null, $match[0]);
    $name   = str_replace(' ', null, strtolower($value));
    return sprintf('<a name="%s"></a>%s', $name, $value);
}, $html);

echo $html;

/*
    <p>Text here ok</p>
    <h4><a name="box1.2"></a>Box 1.2</h4>
    <p>Text here ok</p>
*/
```

Comment: @anubhava: yes, may be any other tags but the concern is the word "Box". It's part of another file which looks for the boxed anchors in here.